# how to use a callback from a pysnmp V3 command responder?

Tags: callback, command, agent, pysnmp

I am using latest version of pysnmp 4.2.4 and have tested the SNMPV1/2C command responder example (http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/v1arch/agent/cmdrsp.html) which is returning an Uptime value in response to OID 1,3,6,1,2,1,1,3,0

I have used the V3 responder example (http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/v3arch/agent/cmdrsp/v3-multiple-users.html) and have that returning the system value (none) for 1,3,6,1,2,1,1,3,0.

How can I add a call back to the V3 version so that it calls an Uptime class similar to the V1 version (and returns a local value)?

TIA
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The v3 model introduces a notion of MIB instrumentation controller class which provides callbacks - one for read and the other for set operations. Stock MIB controller implementation invokes Managed Object Instances Python objects (each identified by an OID) to get/set their values.

So you could either setup your own MibInstrumentatonController class (see EchoMibInstrumController [here](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/v3arch/agent/cmdrsp/v3-alternative-mib-controller.html)) or use stock MIB controller with your own Managed Object Instances (see MyStaticMibScalarInstance [here](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/v3arch/agent/cmdrsp/v2c-custom-scalar-mib-objects.html)).

The SNMPv3 settings in these examples are slightly different but that is not relevant to MIB implementation.